# Reverse assignment in PHP ( LEFT to RIGHT )

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I have the below condition:

```
if (isset($x)){
   $y_class = 'new value';
}else { 
   $z_class = 'new value';
}
```

Can I change the above `if` condition into a ternary? By this, I mean, is there any way to  assign  **LEFT** to **RIGHT**?

Imaginary code:

```
'new value' = (isset($x)) ? $y_class : $z_class;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that : `${(isset($x)?$y_class:$z_class)} = 'new value';`

Mandatory link to the php documentation about [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: exactly what i was thinking .. +1 for being faster than me

Answer (score 7):

Well, if `$y_class` and `$z_class` are hard-coded, you can do something like this, but this just makes your code less readable:

```
$var = isset($x) ? "y_class" : "z_class";
$$var = 'new value';
```

And of course this is still an assignment from right to left; as far as I know, there is no such syntax in the language which would allow assignment from left to right.

Comment: thats fine **but** if `$y_class` and `$z_class` are not hard-coded then

Comment: Well, they do not necessarily have to be hard-coded, you can just as well "calculate" the variable names somehow, but you have to be extra careful not to allow the user to manipulate variables you don't want to. For instance, if the name of the variable comes from a GET parameter and you do not validate it, you practically allow the user to overwrite any of your variables.

Comment: I've given this +1 because it's the closest you'll get to what you're trying to do, but to be honest, I'd just stick with the `if/else` code you have, because that double-dollar syntax is nasty; it's almost bad as `eval()` in the list of things I don't ever want to see in a PHP program.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest implementation i could create. (Essentially a combination of the top 2 answers).

```
${(isset($x) ? 'y':'z'). '_class'} = 'new value';
```

I initially thought to use the [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) language construct, its not as small but i implemented it anyway.

```
list($y_class, $z_class) = isset($x) ? ['new value', $z_class] : [ $y_class, 'new value'];
```

If it's possible that $y_class or $z_class are not set then you would have to do

```
list($y_class, $z_class) = isset($x) ? ['new value', isset($z_class) ? $z_class : null] : [ isset($y_class) ? $y_class : null, 'new value'];
```

both list examples would result in both the variables being assigned a value.